# Magento : Transactional email’s design getting distracted in outlook

Tags: outlook, transactional

I have created one transactional email. 
Its design is getting distracted in Outlook express. 
Can anybody suggest what’s going wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We actually just covered the higher level rendering problems on our blog: http://blog.jangomail.com/2013/04/email-rendering.html.

Outlook can drive you crazy with email rendering issues. Start with your tables and make sure every table and column has a width. Make sure all your images have a set width and height as well. It helps to avoid CSS when possible. Other things to try - replace floats, div's, background images, padding, and margins with simple HTML. Sometimes you even need to replace the spaces between words with   if the words are pushing together. You can also try replacing new paragraphs with `<br />`. If your whitespace isn't showing up well, try making a white image with a set width and height and put it in the email.

Also, check all of your HTML and make sure you aren't missing any end tags and fix any HTML errors.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Melissa

Marketing Director
JangoMail.com